# PHP4: Wrong date

Tags: date, php4

Apart from the discussion about old software, there's a problem with a PHP 4.3.10 instance in Apache 1.3.33.

This is the server date:

```
$ date
Qua Nov 14 11:41:25 BRST 2012
```

The PHP date seems to be correct:

```
echo '<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i") . "\n"; ?>' | php
2012-11-14 11:41
```

However, the very same `<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i"); ?>` in a file accessed via HTTP will show:

```
2012-11-14 10:41
```

How can I set PHP4 to get the same server time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came to the solution:

In this version of Apache and PHP, if you change the server time, then you must restart Apache for the changes to take effect.